# pMOSFET reverse Drain-Source current

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to understand pMOSFET. I searched online tutorial saying that pMOSFET is like a closed switch if V(gs) < V(threshold), like a open switch if V(gs) > V(threshold), V(threshold) typically -1.5V.

But when I do an online simulation, it show the following result. Does anyone know why the left one has current from Drain to Source but the right one doesn't ? Left one does't satisfy V(gs) < V(threshold) condition to closed the switch, but still has current flows. And why sometimes the gate, drain or source is in green, sometimes in shadow ?

[image: pMOSFET]

Comment: The body diode is conducting on the left simulation. The body diode is a parasitic diode created between the body and the drain.

Answer (score 2):

MOSFETs have a **body diode** which will conduct when the MOSFET is "backwards biased": in the case of a PMOS, when the drain-source voltage is greater than a diode drop.

It helps to have a MOSFET symbol which has the body diode included:

[image: PMOS with body diode]

This is an inherent "feature" or MOSFETs: in order to make MOSFETs work reliably, they end up with this body diode. In many applications: H-bridges, ideal rectifiers, etc, they come in handy, in others, not so much. However, that is simply part of the fun of using MOSFETs. For more information, see [Wikipedia: MOSFET body diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_MOSFET#Body_diode) and [Digikey: Intrinsic Body Diodes](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2016/sep/the-significance-of-the-intrinsic-body-diodes-inside-mosfets).

So, don't connect your MOSFETs upside-down :)

Comment: If I connect MOSFET upside-down, it will act exactly the same as a normal Diode ?

Answer (score 1):

In a P-channel MOSFET, the source needs to be more positive than the drain, otherwise the terminals switch roles.  That means that in figure 1, the bottom electrode is acting as the source even though it is supposed to be the drain.  In this case, Vgs is -5, since the gate is at 0V and the source is at +5.

Second, the MOSFET has a body diode that will conduct if the drain-to-source voltage is reversed.  So even if you applied 5V to the gate -- which would turn off the MOSFET channel, you would still have conduction via the body diode.

Comment: The terminals switch roles? I have never heard that one before.

Comment: Actually, you can very readily see that this is not true. That the terminals do not switch roles. If that were really true, then the FET would turn on in "reverse active" mode and short out the body diode, leaving it unbiased. But that is not what happens. The body diode remains forward biased.

Comment: In a normal switching application, the body diode keeps the reverse voltage from building up enough to make it turn on.  But in ICs where the body terminal might be connected elsewhere, the MOSFET becomes a roughly symmetrical device with respect to source drain.

Comment: Interesting. It has been a long time since I did coursework on FET circuits, and I didn't go into IC design. But I surely do not remember ever hearing this concept before. There are diagrams in IC datasheets, though, that show one FET which can control current flow in both directions (e.g., TI power path chargers). I think there is some mention of controlling the bias of the body diode. But the diagrams are not detailed enough to show how it all works.

Comment: @Evan , the second point you mentioned, for example, in Figure1, because of the body diode of MOSFET and Vds is positive enough, the gate voltage can not control the drain->source current ?